# Using images in Type.JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know how I can use images in Type.js rather than strings? I am trying to use images of text I created in Photoshop. Hoping to accomplish something like this. Thanks in advance for any help, I appreciate it.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/typed.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".element").typed({
      image: ['images_folder/foo.png', 'images_folder/bar.png'],
      typeSpeed: 30
    });
  });
</script>
```